# C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake Quickstart in R

Tags: r, c3ai-datalake

I am working on a research assignment on COVID and using the datalake API to fetch different kind of datasets available to us.

I am wondering if it's possible to fetch all outbreak countries.

**ids = list("Australia"),** this works with individual country, it doesnt seem to accept wildcard or all.

Can anyone give me any insights on this please.

```
# Total number of confirmed cases in Australia and proportion of getting infected.
today <- Sys.Date()

casecounts <- evalmetrics(
  "outbreaklocation",
  list(
    spec = list(
      **ids = list("Australia"),**
      expressions = list("JHU_ConfirmedCasesInterpolated","JHU_ConfirmedDeathsInterpolated"),
      start = "2019-12-20",
      end = today-1,
      interval = "DAY"
    )
  )
)

casecounts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to access a list of countries is in the Excel file linked at https://c3.ai/covid-19-api-documentation/#tag/OutbreakLocation. It has a list of countries in the first sheet, and shows which of those have data from JHU.

You could also fetch an approximate list of country-level locations with:

```
locations <- fetch(
    "outbreaklocation",
    list(
      spec = list(
        filter = "not(contains(id, '_'))"
      )
    )
)
```

That should contain all of the countries, but could have some non-countries like World Bank regions.

Then, you'd use this code to get the time series data for all of those locations:

```
location_ids <- 
  locations %>% 
  dplyr::select(-location) %>% 
  unnest_wider(fips, names_sep = ".") %>% 
  sample_n(15) %>% # include this to test on a smaller set
  pull(id)

today <- Sys.Date()

casecounts <- evalmetrics(
  "outbreaklocation",
  list(
    spec = list(
      ids = location_ids,
      expressions = list("JHU_ConfirmedCasesInterpolated","JHU_ConfirmedDeathsInterpolated"),
      start = "2019-12-20",
      end = today-1,
      interval = "DAY"
    )
  ),
  get_all = TRUE
)

casecounts
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I had another look on C3AI, it looks like you can only use 10 country ids per post call. "The number of ids specified in this array must be less or equal to 10." Thanks for sharing, also I find the location needs to be converted to vector.

Comment: The API does have a limit of 10 IDs, but the most up-to-date quickstart notebook (the one that's currently linked on the API doc page) has a "get_all" parameter in evalmetrics that runs as many API calls as needed to get data for a longer list of IDs or expressions.

I'm not sure on the vector part. I just ran the two snippets in my answer and I didn't get any errors about vectors; maybe it has to do with specific R packages?

Comment: Hi Robert, the error i am getting here is:  Error in evalmetrics("outbreaklocation", list(spec = list(ids = location_ids,  : 
  unused argument (get_all = TRUE).  I think the get_all = TRUE probably doesnt work with evalmetrics but fetch? thanks again for looking into this. I hope this is useful for someone else too:)